# BETWEENで一定間隔のデータを抜き出すにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Tags: sql, vba

現在、1秒間隔でcsvファイルにデータを記録しています。
このデータから1分間隔のデータを抽出したいと考えています。

BETWEENを使って一定期間のデータを抜き出すことには成功しましたが、それは1秒間隔のデータなのでそこから更に1分間隔のデータに変更するのに少し時間を要しています。

開発環境はVBAです。

そもそも、BETWEENでそういったことが出来るか分かっていませんのでご教授をお願いします。

補足:
コードはこちらになります。
これで期間1から期間2の間のデータを抜き出しています。

```
SELECT dt,ch1 FROM [data.csv] WHERE dt BETWEEN {日時1} AND {日時2}
```

これですと期間内のデータが1秒間隔で抽出されます。

```
2021/12/27 10:00:00,25.0
2021/12/27 10:00:01,25.3
2021/12/27 10:00:02,25.7
2021/12/27 10:00:03,26.1
･･･
2021/12/27 10:01:00,31.2
2021/12/27 10:01:01,31.4
```

いまはこのデータを更にループ文などで処理して下記1分間隔のデータを抽出しています。

```
2021/12/27 10:00:00,25.0
2021/12/27 10:01:00,31.2
2021/12/27 10:02:00,35.7
2021/12/27 10:03:00,36.5
```

補足:
2022-01-18
こちらのSQL文を実行すると"１つ以上の必要なパラメーターの値が設定されていません。"という実行時エラーが発生します。

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE DATEPART(minute, InspectionDate) = 55"
```

minuteを'で括ると実行時エラーが"プロシージャ呼び出しが正しくありません。"に変わりました。

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE DATEPART('minute', InspectionDate) = 55"
```

参照設定でMicrosoft AvtiveX Data Object 2.8 Libraryを設定しています。

このDLLからADODB.ConnectionとADODB.Recordsetを実装してSQLを実行しています。

Comment: VBAに`BETWEEN`という演算子他は存在しません。またsqlタグが付けられていますがVBAにSQL機能は存在しません。質問の環境が適切に説明できていないように思われます。例えばAccessを使用している、SQL Serverにxxxというドライバで接続している、などありませんか？

Comment: 参照設定でMicrosoft AvtiveX Data Object 2.8 Libraryを設定しています このDLLからADODB.ConnectionとADODB.Recordsetを実装してSQLを実行しています

Comment: 状況が掴みにくいので、1秒間隔のデータを抜き出しているコードとその抽出結果、さらに期待する抽出結果があると答えやすくなると思います。抽出結果は仮のものでよいです。

Comment: いま使用しているSQL文と簡単な結果、欲しい状態を追加してみました

Comment: 秒単位のデータに欠落が無いなら、例えばこの記事 [SQL: Filter data by datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29501999/9014308) を応用して秒の部分が`0`丁度という条件を追加してみては？ データベースソフト毎に使える関数は違うかもしれませんが。

Comment: "DATEPART"を使用してみましたが上手くいきませんでした。補足で追加していますのでSQL文的に間違っている部分があればご教授願います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1秒間隔のデータから1分ごとのデータを抽出したいならば、秒を固定するとよいです。
また、1時間ごとのデータを抽出したいならば、分と秒の両方を固定する必要があります。

---

SQL の関数は RDBMS ごとに異なることがあるので、使っている RDBMS に合わせて都度調べる必要があります。

ACE プロバイダを利用している場合、
分を指定したいならば

```
SELECT * FROM [data.csv] WHERE dt BETWEEN ? AND ? AND DATEPART('n', dt) = 0;
```

秒を指定したいのならば

```
SELECT * FROM [data.csv] WHERE dt BETWEEN ? AND ? AND DATEPART('s', dt) = 0;
```

でどうでしょうか

https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/datepart-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa

Answer (score 1):

無事に解決できました。
v..snowさん、コメントを下さった方々、ありがとうございます。
最終的にこちらのSQL文で抽出したい部分のデータが抜けるようになりました。

```
SELECT dt,ch1 FROM [data.csv] WHERE dt BETWEEN {日時1} AND {日時2} AND DATEPART('n', InspectionDate) = 0
```

迷って部分としては、日時部分を#を括る必要がありました。
これを怠ると"構文エラー：演算子がありません"とエラーが発生しました。